# use loop function that calls itself instead of nesting loops to iterate through object of objects of arrays, but running into async issues

Tags: javascript

I have an object called `foods` that contains different categories of foods as objects. Each of those object "categories" contains an array of food items in their respective categories. I'm trying to iterate through this, creating `meal` objects that include one food item from each category. I then take the `meal` objects and store them in a container array called `meals`. My goal is to have the container array contain every possible combo of food items. Instead of writing a series of nested loops, I'm trying to write one loop function that calls itself, but I think some index values increment faster than the loop function is called, giving me issues.

The nested loops below work. Note that the `meals` container array contains over 100 `meal` objects upon completion:

```
var meals = [];
var meal = {};
var foods = {veggies:["asparagus","broccoli"],meat:["chicken","steak"],dessert:["pudding","ice cream"]};
var keys = Object.keys(foods);

for (var i = 0; i < foods[keys[0]].length; i++) {
    meal[keys[0]] = foods[keys[0]][i];
    for (var j = 0; j < foods[keys[1]].length; j++) {
        meal[keys[1]] = foods[keys[1]][j];
        for (var k = 0; k < foods[keys[2]].length; k++) {
            meal[keys[2]] = foods[keys[2]][k];
            meals.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(meal)));
        }
    }
}
```

This (below) is how I'm trying to do it using a loop function, but it does not work, as the `meals` container array contains far fewer than the number of possible combos upon completion. Is there a way to make something like this work using a callback, promise or something else?

```
var meals = [];
var meal = {};
var foods = {veggies:["asparagus","broccoli"],meat:["chicken","steak"],dessert:["pudding","ice cream"]};
var keys = Object.keys(foods);

function runLoop(foodTypeNumber) {
    for (var i = 0; i < foods[keys[foodTypeNumber]].length; i++) {
        meal[keys[foodTypeNumber]] = foods[keys[foodTypeNumber]][i];
        if (keys.length > foodTypeNumber + 1) {
            runLoop(foodTypeNumber + 1);
        } else {
            meals.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(meal)));
        }
    }
}

runLoop(0);
```

I've also noticed that when I take the code above and increment `foodTypeNumber` right before the `if` statement, I get a different result. Can someone help me understand what is going on here?

```
var meals = [];
var meal = {};
var foods = {veggies:["asparagus","broccoli"],meat:["chicken","steak"],dessert:["pudding","ice cream"]};
var keys = Object.keys(foods);

function runLoop(foodTypeNumber) {
    for (var i = 0; i < foods[keys[foodTypeNumber]].length; i++) {
        meal[keys[foodTypeNumber]] = foods[keys[foodTypeNumber]][i];
        foodTypeNumber++;
        if (keys.length > foodTypeNumber) {
            runLoop(foodTypeNumber);
        } else {
            meals.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(meal)));
        }
    }
}

runLoop(0);
```

Comment: No asynchronous code here, so no, it's not an asynchrony issue.

Comment: Tbh actually it's your original code that is broken and generates far too many combinations (containing duplicates and empty ones). You'll need to have each loop go to `foods[keys[…]].length`, not to `keys[1].length`.

Comment: "*I've also noticed that when I take the code above and increment foodTypeNumber right before the if statement, I get a different result*" - that's because you're incrementing in a loop, not only once per function call.

Comment: You are correct, my original loops were incorrect and my function loop is actually working properly when I don't increment within the loop.